# FP: cómo accedo a una lista privada sin método público que acceda a ella?

Tags: java

Le he dado muchas vueltas y o el enunciado está mal o yo estoy más perdido de lo que creía.

Tengo una clase Alumno que tiene un Array List de una clase Asignatura.

Esta clase asignatura tiene un array list privado de la clase nota.

Nota tiene un int privado y un geter público.

En la clase alumno tengo un método que suma en un solo objeto De notas todas las notas de cada asignatura.

Intuyo que se recorre la lista de Asignaturas y por cada elemento se recorre su lista de notas sumando estas.

El caso es que está lista es privada y no puedo acceder a los objetos de nota que si tienen un geter público.

Alguna idea?

Comment: Aquí quizá entren en juego algunas cosas como la herencia. Sin ver un ejemplo mínimo y verificable sólo podremos intentar adivinar. Pulsa en [edit] y muestra lo que tienes hecho, y qué problemas o errores tienes.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Asignatura {
    private List<Nota> notas = new ArrayList<>();

    public Nota getNotas() {
        return notas;
    }
}

public class Nota {
    private int valor;

    public Nota( int vale ) {
        valor = vale;
    }
    public int getNota() {
        return valor;
    }
}

public class Alumno {
    List<Asignatura> asignaturas = new ArrayList<>();

    Nota sumarNotas( int asignatura ) {    
        int acumulador = 0;        
        for( int i = 0; i < notas.size(); i++ ) {
            Notes notas = asignatura.get( i ).getNotas();
            for( int k = 0; k < asigna.size(); k++ ) {
                acumulador += notas.get( i ).getNota();
            }
        }
        return new Nota( acumulado );
    }
}
```

Como verás, seguí las indicaciones, solo creé el método **sumarNotas**, que recorre la lista de asignaturas, pidiéndole a cada una, la lista de notas.   Luego en el `for` interno, le pido a cada nota su valor nominal, y lo agrego al acumulador.
Finalmente creo un nuevo objeto **Nota**, con el valor de **acumulador**.
La idea detrás de las clases, es que no se pueda acceder a los atributos, si no es por medio de sus respectivos `getters`.